# Bot engine not sending any response to facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I've a nodejs server application and I've exposed the URL using ngrok. That URL is being used as a callback URL in facebook webhook. There is no problem with webhook validation. Why is it that I cannot receive the replies from the bot engine when I send messages from my facebook messenger? When I run the program on command prompt and provide the wit token, the program runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing the bot with your admin profile its should workes , if you are not , you must add the bot to facebook aps and get accepted by facebook devlopers than u cant use it with other profiles

Comment: Testing it with admin profile but it's still not working.